# How can I solve the following exercise

Tags: measure-theory

How can I solve the following exercise : 
Why every simple function is measurable function ?? 
And 
The measurable function is simple function if its range is a finite subset of $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition: A simple function is a finite linear combination of indicator functions of measurable sets. You can check it's a measurable function because its range set just has finite numbers.

Comment: Definition: a function is a measurable function if for every t, $  set \{ x : f(x)>t \}$ is a measurable set. Can you find out that simple functions satisfy this definition ?